# How do I run C++ 17 as default with clang on macOS?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, clang

When I try to run this simple helloworld programm with clang++ -o helloworld helloworld.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};

    for (const string& word : msg)
    {
        cout << word << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

with clang++ -o helloworld helloworld.cpp, I get the following error

helloworld.cpp:9:23: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
vector msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};
^
;
helloworld.cpp:11:29: warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
for (const string& word : msg)
^
1 warning and 1 error generated.

This error does not appear when I compile it with clang++ -std=c++17 helloworld helloworld.cpp
Somehow it seems that clang is using an older c++ version than c++11. How do I set c++17 as the default? I could just alias the command but eventually I would like to use vs code and this wouldn't solve the problem there. My clang version is 14.0.3.

Comment: VS code has project settings.  In those settings, one of them lets you specify the C++ standard you want.  Use that, don't rely on a compiler default.  It makes the code less portable that way.

Comment: Apple Clang defaults to C++98. There is no way you can change that. Be sure you always set a newer C++ standard from the project settings.

Comment: so I went to extension settings and searched for cppstandard and chose c++17 from the list but the problem remains. Is this what you meant or how do I change the project settings?

Comment: This official VSCode macOS clang documentation shows you the 3 important json files and has the 2 modifications for c++17: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac)

Comment: yeah I actually went through this step by step, but still I get an compiler error

Comment: By defining a shell alias (or shell function or shell script).  I use `g++` more often on linux and I use `alias g17='g++ -std=c++17'` which works great interactively (where I care). If you need it "as a command" a simple shell script (also taking in `"$@"` to pass args along) is possibly your new best friend.

Comment: ***yeah I actually went through this step by step, but still I get an compiler error*** Are you sure it's using your tasks.json by looking at the generated commands in the terminal? Also are you using code-runner? The official documentation does not work with code runner. When you use the tasks.json from the documentation you should see the `-std=c++17` in the build command in the terminal.  If you don't its not using your tasks.json

Comment: "/usr/bin/clang++ -fcolor-diagnostics -fansi-escape-codes -g /Users/arcadiobuendia/projects/helloworld/helloworld.cpp -o /Users/arcadiobuendia/projects/helloworld/helloworld
/Users/arcadiobuendia/projects/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:9:23: error: expected ';' at end of declaration" this is the first part of the error I get when running it in vs code

Comment: {
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
        "args": [
          "-std=c++17",
          "-stdlib=libc++",
          "-g",
          "${file}",
          "-o",
          "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
      }
    ]
  }

Comment: this is my task.json. the same as in the link

Comment: Your task does not appear to be used.

Comment: Do you know how to change that?

Comment: Your tasks.json could be in the wrong folder or not match the choice you are given when you tell it to build from the IDE. '"C/C++: clang++ build active file" provided you are not using code-runner which is a different method than using tasks.json. Or maybe the tasks.json is not saved.

Comment: task.json is definetly safed and in the correct order. when I run a file nevertheless the task.json file gets rewritten and the type changes from shell to cppbuild.